# can't run script/console from ubuntu upgrade 9.10 -> 10.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ubuntu-10.04

I just upgraded my ubuntu from 9.10 to 10.04,
before the upgrade everything was fine, but after the upgrade I can no 
longer run script/console.

```
Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.10)
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:779:in 
`report_activate_error':Gem::LoadError: RubyGem version error: 
rails(2.3.4 not = 2.3.10)

/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/init.rb:264:in `require':LoadError: no such file 
to load -- console_app
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/init.rb:264:in `require':LoadError: no such file 
to load -- console_with_helpers
# gem -v
1.5.2
# ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [i686-linux]
# rails -v
Rails 2.3.10
```

Google was not much help so far :(

Update:
After trying several options, I updated to 10.10 and now getting following errors

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [i686-linux]
$ gem -v
1.6.2
$ rails -v
Rails 2.3.10

$ gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.6.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2010-08-18 patchlevel 0) [i686-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - /home/recmend/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
$ whereis ruby
ruby: /usr/bin/ruby1.8 /usr/bin/ruby /usr/lib/ruby /usr/local/bin/ruby /usr/local/lib/ruby /usr/share/man/man1/ruby.1.gz
$ whereis gem
gem: /usr/bin/gem /usr/local/bin/gem

$ script/console 
Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.10)
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:68:in `installed_spec_directories': undefined method `path' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:58:in `from_installed_gems'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:883:in `source_index'
```

Off to next problem...

Comment: It looks like you are trying to run your app using Rails v2.3.10, but have Rails 2.3.4 installed. Have you tried running `gem install rails --version 2.3.10` or altering your gemfile to use what you currently have installed (2.3.4)?

Comment: # gem list -d rails

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rails (2.3.10, 2.3.5)
    Author: David Heinemeier Hansson
    Rubyforge: http://rubyforge.org/projects/rails
    Homepage: http://www.rubyonrails.org
    Installed at (2.3.10): /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
                 (2.3.5): /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1

Do I need to update my gem file? My environment also has 2.3.10

Comment: @Anshu: do you have a verion of Rails within the `vendor/rails` directory of your application?

Comment: `$ ls vendor/ 
plugins`
Nothing as vendor/rails... Weird thing just before upgrade to 10.04 everything was working as fine. Now having this error.

Comment: Could you run `gem environment` and post the results here? I've seen multiple ruby binaries installed with different gem locations and Rails gets confused sometimes. Also try running `/usr/bin/env ruby -v` and see if it's any different than `ruby -v`.

Comment: Thanks for helping but I'm still stuck. Updated the question.

Comment: please remove all existing rails gems with `gem uninstall rails -v 2.3.x` check if You get the message and if not then install again `gem install -v 2.3.10` - it seams insane but maybe some old file from previous system is left somewhere on disk

Answer (score 1):

the problem is in your Rubies versions. You see:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [i686-linux]
```

but 
Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.10) /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/**1.9.1**/rubygems.rb:779:in

It is trying to load 1.9.1 with all its gems.

What you can do here.

1. `which ruby` will return your Ruby 1.9.2 dir
2. add it into your PATH `export PATH=/your/ruby1.9.2/dir/bin:$PATH`

enjoy :)